# Should I use os.path.exists before os.makedirs?

Tags: python-3.x

Should I use os.path.exists before os.makedirs with exist_ok=True or not?
It doesn't matter if I don't have permission to that folder.
From my testing it seems roughly 3 times as fast to check the file path first and it makes my code better readable. Or am I missing something?

```
import timeit
import os
def mkdirs(file_path):
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        os.makedirs(file_path, exist_ok = True)

file_path = "/Users/wannes/Downloads/untitled folder"
print("#0", timeit.timeit('''mkdirs(file_path)''', globals=globals(), number=100000))
print("#1", timeit.timeit('''os.makedirs(file_path, exist_ok = True)''', globals=globals(), number=100000))

#0 0.28453361399806454
#1 0.8769928680012526
```

This is used to extract & convert files from a zip which means I need to do this check for every file as I can't get a list of folders. Of course then this makes a difference.

Comment: Your `test` function is a textbook example of a [time-of-check to time-of-use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) bug

Comment: Race condition possible if someone makes the directory after the existence is checked.

Comment: So, what is more important to you, a few microseconds or the simpler code? I guess the difference because `makedirs` does some extra work first hand to check the parent directories.

Comment: @Nineteendo: You'd still need the `exist_ok=True`, or you'd need to be prepared for the possibility of any folder (possibly a mid-path symlink) deleted in between the test and the check. Granted, you're kinda stuck there anyway (because it could be deleted immediately *after* you create it, and that would probably cause a problem in the subsequent code using it), but given how trivial the overhead here is (about 6 microseconds per call), *anything* but the simplest possible code (`'os.makedirs(file_path, exist_ok=True)` alone) is premature optimization.

Comment: @Nineteendo: Yes, I see that, I was responding to your comment saying "The code becomes even simpler then, because you don't need to use exist_ok=True."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. According to your microbenchmark, the per-call additional overhead (when the directory already exists) is six *micro*seconds. If you did this 1000 times, it would still be faster than a human can perceive. If *the* hot path in your code is creating directories that might already exist, something is very wrong; if it's not the hot path, the overhead is *irrelevant*. In your case, the work spent extracting/decompressing files from the zip file in the first place should outweigh any overhead of the simplest code (plain `os.makedirs(file_path, exist_ok=True)`) by multiple orders of magnitude. It's just not worth worrying about.
2. This is no more readable because it replaces a documented, fairly well-known API call with something that's clearly in-house and may (or may not) do what I expect. If I see `os.makedirs(file_path, exist_ok=True)` I know *exactly* what it does, because I've used that API before, in multiple projects. If I see `mkdirs(file_path)` I:

   a. Can guess at the meaning (and I'd be right), but

   b. Can't trust that it's correct without looking up the definition of `mkdirs` (for one thing, I won't know if it's *supposed* to handle/ignore the case of the directory already existing), and

   c. I'll almost certainly go check, because reimplementing existing functionality like this is a form of code smell, and I'd want to know why someone didn't just do the straightforward thing with `os.makedirs`.

**TL;DR: You're engaging in premature optimization. Writing a new wrapper for every call to save trivial amounts of processor time is not worth the trouble, and makes for less maintainable code. Just use the API directly until profiling proves microoptimizations matter in the *real* code.**

Comment: You're right that it's insignificant. (But it will make a small difference.)
For the name, you could use mkdirs_exist_ok_if_not_exists but that's pushing it at bit too far I believe.

Comment: @Nineteendo: Right. But who cares if the code runs a few microseconds faster if each new person maintaining your code must spend even 10 seconds rechecking something trivial? The whole point of Python and other high-level languages is reducing developer/maintainer effort at the expense of runtime performance. If you wanted maximum performance, just write C or C++ or Rust or whatever. Factoring out snippets this short just to get maximally concise code and a trivial performance boost is pretty pointless.